# How to convert 'AccountId' into 'ValidAccountId' in Near protocol contracts?

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

I want to know the function caller's ID and check his balance. Issue is that `env::signer_account_id()` returns data of type `AccountId`/`String` while function `ft_balance_of()` needs an input of type `ValidAccountId`. `ft_balance_of()` is an [NEP-141 fungible token function](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/42107dcdd0fafecc1b8ac6ee0e4f60eabe56a651/near-contract-standards/src/fungible_token/macros.rs#L34).

```rust
let current_user = env::signer_account_id();

let balance = self.ft_balance_of(current_user); // error
```

Error message in VS Code

```
mismatched types
expected struct `near_sdk::json_types::ValidAccountId`, found struct `std::string::String`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ValidAccountId` is a wrapper around a `AccountId`, which validates the string to ensure that it is a valid format.  This is usually done when deserializing the JSON sent when calling the contract method.  However, here you have to be explicit:

```rust
// use try_into because it could fail to validate.
let balance = self.ft_balance_of(current_user.try_into().unwrap());
```

See test here:
https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/1951284503168c4e842e957e172c3b12c3c46240/near-sdk/src/json_types/account.rs#L90

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on the answer from @sirwillem, but one thing to note with that is you need to import the `std::convert::TryInto` trait to use that method.

You could also use the [TryFrom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) trait if it makes it any easier.

I've just put a [PR](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/pull/391) in to implement the [FromStr](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) trait for the type so that you don't need to import any trait and instead just call `.parse()`. This won't be available until it gets pulled in and released, though.